# Openfire websocket configuration

Tags: websocket, openfire

Hi I have installed Openfire and the plugin for websocket from the link (https://code.google.com/p/openfire-websockets/downloads/detail?name=websockets-0.0.0.6.zip&can=2&q=) When I install the the plugin, the plugin is available in the openfire plugin's. But the question is how do I configure, and how to access the WS.

Cheers
Sunil

Answer (score 3):

For checking WebSocket

```
Socket = new WebSocket("ws://domain:7070/ws/",'xmpp')
```

Don't forget for `'xmpp'` protocol

Answer (score 1):

please go through the installation steps given in the link [here openfire-server-configuration](http://blog.e-zest.com/openfire-server-configuration). It might prove helpful to install and configure your plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've installed the plugin (make sure you restart the server), you should be able to reach the Websocket connector via `ws://domain:port/ws/`, `port` usually being 7070. Check the `Server > Server Settings > HTTP Binding` menu in the web interface if you're not sure.

However you don't get to configure much. The Websocket plugin is very minimalistic, it will basically reuse the existing BOSH (plain HTTP) configuration, but that's usually enough.